# Comparing UITableViews in one View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

```
@property (nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UITableView *ilacOrderTableView;    
@property (nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UITableView *ilacListesiTableView;

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
            if(tableView.tag==0){ 
            }       
  }
```

or

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(tableView==self.ilacListesiTableView){ 
    }
}
```

doesn't work. Why doesn't it work? Thank you.

**I forgot to write here. One of the tableviews belongs to UISearchDisplayController.**

Comment: Show your tableView intialization code. Both will work. But second condition looks good.

Comment: doesn't work?? what do you mean?

Comment: The first one is common. But both will work.

Comment: It has to go both true and false part for the specific tableview. But only goes to one tableview.

Comment: have you set connection and delegate for both.?

Comment: what is self.mytableview?? As from code u provided I couldnt see that var!! EDIT: thanks for changing ur code after my comment and even for not mentioning there!!

Comment: Thank you all. And sorry @NSS about not mentioning. Next time I will ,about a situation like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView == self.tableView)
    {
        // Return a standard listing for indexPath.
    }
    else if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.tableView)
    {
        // Return a filtered cell, based on a filtered model of the searchDisplayController's searchBar's search string.
    }
}
```

Comment: But why doesn't the other codes worked?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this one.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ([self.ilacListesiTableView isEqual:tableView]) {

    } else if ([self.searchDisplayController.tableView isEqual:tableView]) {

    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and didn't work. The answer is the best for my condition cause of the searchdisplaycontroller.

Comment: This is just an idea that you can also write like above for comparison of two objects.